# Loading Circle in Visual C# 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

Instead of a regular progress bar, how can I make a circle with spokes that rotate telling the user that that my program is loading?

EDIT: I want it in Windows Forms

Ok thanks Tim, your solution works. I had to set the image by code since importing it in the designer froze it up.

Answer (score 12):

I normally go to http://ajaxload.info/ and put one of their animated GIFs in a `PictureBox`.

Comment: This is a feasible solution, but doesn't really look good when the background has some color other than white. Even though the background can be made transparent, it looks ugly.

Answer (score 0):

This is the one I actually used in one of my apps
[Circular Progress indicator](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/progress/ProgressIndicator.aspx).[This second](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/49853/Better-WPF-Circular-Progress-Bar.aspx) one is for WPF apps.